# React PureComponent vs Component in case of counts of rendering same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React class module, If counts of rendering in PureComponent are same as ones of it in Component, which one should I use? PureComponent is always faster, better than Component?

```
render(){

       //console.log('rendered');

return(<div>...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without measuring, it is hard to say.

`PureComponent` is nothing fancy, it justs handles `shouldComponentUpdate` method automatically for you.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return stuffChanged(this, nextProps, nextState))
  }
```

Let's say `stuffChanged` is a function which does heavy computation and thus takes considerable amount of time too.

So now `react` will spend time in running this function (diffing) and then also in updating the DOM.

Whereas, if you did not have `shouldComponentUpdate` method, then your component will not have to spend time in running `stuffChanged` expensive function.

It will update the DOM if diffing and reconciliation of react tells it to.

So, if you just have a `Component` there is one diff i.e updating the DOM.

But if you have a `PureComponent` there is atleast one diff and sometimes two i.e diffing for state and props and then updating the DOM.

Which means `PureComponent` is going to be slower usually but faster occasionally.

Unless you have measured your performance of the app with some profiling tool, I would suggest you to just stick to `Component`.

If you wrap use `PureComponent` everywhere without measuring, chances are you would end up slowing your web app.

Answer (score 0):

If said component doesn't have many changing parts (ie, different state or props) then pure component is a simplified way of making sure it doesn't re-render needlessly. Otherwise, use componenetDidUpdate would be a more in-depth way to handle those